# overlay from opencv on top of camera stream

Tags: camera, opencv

I watched [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=b2kGPWxJybo) video. There is a face being tracked by a Raspberry Pi and a frame gets displayed around the face.

I'm interested in creating the overlay with the frame. As you can see, the stream of the camera is fluent in more than 25fps probably. However, the calculation of the tracking frame is slow and has a bit of a lag, but that doesn't influence the actual stream.

How can I do such an overlay?

Comment: A quick search on the internet shows there is plenty of tutorials about face tracking with the Pi.